# On the structure of an integral with a variable upper limit of a continuous periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, periodic-functions

$f$ is continuous and periodic with period T. Show that $F: x \to \int_0^xf(t)dt$ can be represented as a sum of a linear and a periodic function. I have proven that $\int_x^{x+T}f(x)dx=\int_0^Tf(x)dx$, is it useful here?

Comment: *Hint:* Consider the case $\int_0^T f(x) dx = 0$ first. Then reduce the general case to this special case.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try

Comment: If you put $\alpha = T^{-1}\int_0^T f(t)\,dt$, then you can use your previous result to show that $F(x) - \alpha x$ is periodic with period $T$.

Comment: Got it, thank you!